# How do I get data out of a parse.com relation?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, relation

I'm using parse.com as my backend for an iOS Swift app.

I have Posts & Users. A user can like a post.

When I get the list of posts I want to see if the PFUser.Currentuser() has liked each post.

In my current data model I use a relation on the post.

```
    let post = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Post", objectId: postId)
    let relation = post.relationForKey("likers")
    relation.addObject(PFUser.currentUser()!)
    post.saveInBackground()
```

When I query for the posts I put each post into a PostView object.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Post")

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects : [AnyObject]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for (index, object) in enumerate(objects) {
                    //convert PFObject into Post
                    let post = PostView(postQuery: object)
         }         
}
```

I'd like to have a boolean in PostView that is true if the the current user likes the post.

```
class PostView {

var id = ""
var description = ""

var isPostLikedByCurrentUser : Bool?

init(postQuery : PFObject){
    self.id = postQuery.objectId!
    self.description = postQuery["description"] as! String
}
```

I'm simply not sure where or how to get the contents of the relation out. Is it in the query? Or should I do it in PostView and if so how?

I've tried this in PostView

```
    let relation = postQuery.relationForKey("likers")
    let debug = relation.query()?.findObjectsInBackground()
```

The relation works but I don't get any data out into debug.

Help greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

This works but makes a lot of queries... How do I cut it down to just one query? I am happy to change my data model.

```
class PostView {

var id = ""
var description = ""

var isPostLikedByCurrentUser : Bool?

init(postQuery : PFObject){
    self.id = postQuery.objectId!
    self.description = postQuery["description"] as! String

    let relation = postQuery.relationForKey("likers")

    let query = relation.query()

    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects : [AnyObject]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for (index, object) in enumerate(objects) {

                    if (object["email"]?.isEqual(PFUser.currentUser()?.email) != nil)
                    {
                         self.isPostLikedByCurrentUser = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: After talking to more folks it sounds as if the only way to make this into one query is to use cloud code.